# How to stop/pause AP discovery algorithm when connected through console and PC LAN

Tags: cisco-commands

I want to upload the image through TFTP, but as I start, my AP lose connectivity with TFTP and get this message "Could not discover WLC using static IP forcing AP to use DHCP "  is there any way to disable/stop WLC discovery and my AP keep connected with static IP. Please must reply, thanking you in anticipation. Please note that MY LAP/CAP AP is not connected with WLC, only with my laptop, So far I have not found any solution of this problem.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: debug capwap cli no-reload this should work...........please try

Answer (score 2):

A lightweight AP is designed to work only with a controller, so it will keep rebooting until it can find one.

I assume you are trying to convert the AP to autonomous mode.  Follow these instructions:
https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/57476/lwapp-autonomous-conversion-and-vice-versa-access-points

Comment: Mr Ron I got your point, but if I wana use archive upload-sw feature to upload the ISO onto my PC for backup while AP is not connected with controller, however I can stop its rebooting by using no-reload command but cant stop the static IP reverting back to DHCP, that makes tftp disconnected, can I enable the mini DHCP into LAP?

Answer (score 0):

I think the download is erroring out b/c the AP keeps getting a new IP address every time it DHCPs.  Try configuring a static entry in your DHCP server with the MAC address of the AP.  That way, every time the WLC discovery resets and it DHCPs again, it will get the same address, and the transfer won't be interrupted.